How to duplicate a template in wordpress site editor?
How can I create a duplicate of a template using the Wordpress Site Editor?
Using the Wordpress Site Editor, I can create new page templates. I want to create a new template that's nearly identical to an existing template, except for a small change. I could manually try to create all the blocks from the old template in my new template, but that's extremely time-consuming and prone to error.

ⓘ Note: This question is specifically asking about how to manage templates in the Site Editor only. Any answers that involve editing template files outside of the Site Editor are off-topic as they do not answer this question.

Is there a way I can simply create a duplicate of an existing page template when creating a new page template?

This can be achieved by switching from the Visual Editor to the Code Editor
First, open the page template in the Site Editor. Then change from the Visual Editor to the Code Editor. All of the blocks will change from visual blocks to a long plaintext representation of the blocks. Select-all (ctrl+a) and copy this (ctrl-c).
Open your new template in the Site Editor. Then change from the Visual Editor to the Code Editor. Delete the body of the page template, and paste (ctrl-v) what you copied from the other template above. Save.
You should now have a duplicate template.
